# Multivariable black-box function of a unique global minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Assuming a multivariable black-box function $f$. Is there a method (it may be numerical) to prove that $f$ has a **unique** global minimum in a given interval?

Comment: Can we at least assume $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes.

Comment: When you say interval, do you mean (multidimensional) box?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that's it.